# ImportError with "scenarios.py"

Tags: import, drake

Thank you for your help in advance!

I had the following error, for example, when running the first cell in pose.ipynb. I have tried reinstalling drake and manipulation on my local machine with the newest version, but I still have the same problem. Can you please help me out with it?

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 23
9 from pydrake.all import (AbstractValue, AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph, AngleAxis,
10                          BaseField, ConstantValueSource, CsdpSolver,
11                          DepthImageToPointCloud, DiagramBuilder,
(...)
19                          RollPitchYaw, RotationMatrix, Simulator, StartMeshcat,
20                          ge)
22 from manipulation import running_as_notebook
---> 23 from manipulation.scenarios import (AddIiwaDifferentialIK, AddMultibodyTriad,
24                                     AddRgbdSensor, MakeManipulationStation)
25 from manipulation.meshcat_utils import AddMeshcatTriad, draw_open3d_point_cloud
26 from manipulation.utils import AddPackagePaths, FindResource

File ~/manipulation-master/manipulation/scenarios.py:10
7 import warnings
9 import numpy as np
---> 10 from pydrake.all import (
11     AbstractValue, Adder, AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph, BallRpyJoint, BaseField,
12     Box, CameraInfo, ClippingRange, CoulombFriction, Cylinder, Demultiplexer,
13     DepthImageToPointCloud, DepthRange, DepthRenderCamera, DiagramBuilder,
14     FindResourceOrThrow, GeometryInstance, InverseDynamicsController,
15     LeafSystem, LoadModelDirectives, LoadModelDirectivesFromString,
16     MakeMultibodyStateToWsgStateSystem, MakePhongIllustrationProperties,
...
23     DifferentialInverseKinematicsIntegrator,
24     DifferentialInverseKinematicsParameters)
26 from manipulation.utils import AddPackagePaths, FindResource

ImportError: cannot import name 'LoadModelDirectivesFromString' from 'pydrake.all' (/home/obito/env_drake/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/all.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadModelDirectivesFromString` was added to Drake only in the last few days.  You just need to update your installation of Drake.